# Linux localhost port 8080 unresponsive

Tags: linux, vue.js, localhost

I have a vuejs app running on my localhost on port 8080, and when I open it in my browser the site doesn't load, and I get the warning by chrome that the site is not responding. I also have a python flask backend running on port 5000, and this works perfectly. Is this a common issue? If so, how do I resolve it?
Thanks!

Comment: are you certain that the vuejs app is actually listening on port 8080?
Have you tried using something like netstat or netcat to verity the port is open?

Comment: I think so, how do I make sure?

Comment: are you running on Linux?
if so you can do something like `netstat -nlt | grep 8080`

Comment: open Terminal and check your open ports : `netstat -ntlp | grep 8080` and `netstat -ntlp | grep 5000` if they not exists try to restart their service !

Comment: @Freeman for 8080 i get: `tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:8080   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN`
and for 5000: `tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:5000   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   6252/python3`

Comment: So maybe your chrome is behind proxy, check that out or check with another browser, let me know if it won't work again.

Comment: please also check this address too in your address bar : `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Comment: It doesn't work with any browser. I tried chrome and firefox, also tried connecting from a different machine on the same network. The flask API still works perfectly, just not the vuejs app.

Answer (score 0):

OK let us to change default port and try again 
first enter `npm run serve -- --port 4030`
and now again test `http://localhost:4030` if agian not works, all you have to do is modify the portvalue inside the `dev` block in root of your project, for example `<your_project_root>/vue.config.js`

```
    // vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    open: process.platform === 'darwin',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 4030, // Your PORT you changed !
    https: false,
    hotOnly: false,
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :/ . In the tab title it displays the page name properly, and in chrome on the bottom left it says "Waiting for cache". The page itself stays blank though.

Comment: aha it's blank ? without any error ? so maybe `index page` is blank !

Comment: I found the error I think: it was one of the components from Vuetify not rendering correctly which slowed down the whole page. Thanks for the help though!